# Can I download a Excel(.xls) using AgilityPack?

Tags: c#, excel, web-scraping, automation, html-agility-pack

I need to extract an .xls file from a website.

Here is the button:

```
button class="btn btn-success btn-labeled fa fa-file-excel-o" id="btn-Exportar" type="submit">Excel</button
```

The table:

```
table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered text-sm"
```

If I need to give more info let me know.

Comment: It might be easier to recreate the POST request with System.Net.HttpClient than to scrape the page. Have you considered that?

Comment: I will probably do it, I was trying not to because this is an Excel that will change the content constantly, so with Agility Pack I could avoid have to change it in two places